# Python For Loop with File

Tags: python, file, for-loop, input

I'm still learning Python and decided to combine two different elements to understand loops and files better.
I made a simple for loop that takes multiple inputs from the user and writes it into a file.
I read and watch some tutorials on how to work with for loop and files.
What I wanted to do is every time the user writes a line of string a number will be written at the beginning stating the position.

So, if I only write one line then the for loop will also write the number "1" at the beginning.
If I write two lines of strings then it will be

1. string
2. string

The problem I'm having with this is that this method only works if I keep writing different lines of string in that debugging only.

If I stop writing and decide to start the loop again to write a new line then it start with number "1" again. Any idea how can I fix this and why is it happening?

Comment: what is `file` in for loop?

Comment: that's opening and reading the file.

Comment: This code seems incomplete, what is line?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your code is incomplete.

Comment: line is just an int variable equal to 1

Comment: I don't see how my question is wrong. I'm just trying to add an index (numerical order) to every string the user enters for every newline. The problem is that it only works when I run the loop once. If I try to run the loop again then it starts from 1. Like I said, I'm still learning and I won't be able to explain much of it.

Comment: You are opening 2 files and calling both "file". Maybe they should be named file1 and file2?..

Comment: @Joe How do you run the loop again? By copy-pasting that block of code, or by running the whole script again? Also, what's your end goal? Like, what should  `file.txt` look like at each step? I don't understand why you're duplicating each line. I think this is bordering on an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: Okay, so I tried the loop before without the first line and it didn't work because the for loop couldn't work. What I meant before about running the loop is that when I first debug it to ender the string in the command. If I exit that command and then try again then the numbers start from 1 again. The first like for file is just reading what's inside the file and the second one is letting me write into it.

Comment: I explained it above that the results should be something like this,
1.  car
2. sports
3. cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems. So I recreated your code.

```
try:
    with open("file.txt", "r") as l:
        line = int(l.readlines()[-1][0]) + 1
except FileNotFoundError:
    line = 1
```

This tries to read the file and get the last number if it doesn't exist it use 1.

```
with open("file.txt", "a") as f:
    try:
        while True: 
            f.write(f'{line} {input()} \n')
            line += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Quiting...')
```

This is same as your code but I add a way to exit(ctrl+c) without giving an error message.

So the final code will be like this:

```
try:
    with open("file.txt", "r") as l:
        line = int(l.readlines()[-1][0]) + 1
except FileNotFoundError:
    line = 1

with open("file.txt", "a") as f:
    try:
        while True: 
            f.write(f'{line} {input()} \n')
            line += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Quiting...')
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that would be to read the file, then find the most recent line, and get that number.

You would then add 1 to it, and keep going from there

P.S. regex will help